# What is the difference between private member and public member in a base class?

Tags: c++

```
#pragma pack(push, 4)
class Father
{
 public:
  int b;
  char c;
};
class Child : public Father
{
  char e;

};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

sizeof(Father)=8 
 sizeof(Child)=12
 But if We change class Father like this:

```
class Father
{
 private:// change from public
  int b;
  char c;
};
```

sizeof(Child)=8

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate @EricHotinger, I believe he is asking why `sizeof(Child)` is different based on the visibility of the properties in the base class.

Comment: Why the `#pragma`?  They're misleading, since they don't (as far as I can tell) have any effect here.  (I'm compiling in 32 bit mode.)

Answer (score 5):

It's an implementation detail of the compiler. In other words, not really your business, unless you really, really need to make your data as small as possible. Beware premature optimization here.

In the end, it probably comes down to peculiarities of the Common C++ ABI, using terms like "POD for the purpose of layout" and "base class padding reuse".

**Edit:** Or not, because those pragmas suggest you're using Visual Studio. In that case, never forget that the MS ABI is a jungle of wild backwards compatibility hacks.

Answer (score 3):

The difference in size you are seeing is a result of the compatibility to C. C only knows about `struct` where everything is public. So, when you use `public` members in a C++ `struct` or `class`, the ABI is compatible with C, hence it needs to follow the alignment rules of C.

When you declare the members `private`, the C++ ABI has more freedom to optimize the packing of the members.

Comment: C does not have inheritance, so there is no compatibility (at least as far as `Child` is concerned) with C anyway, is there?

Comment: Then why the total size of base class becomes only 4 bytes instead of 8 bytes?

Comment: @hvd Probably not, but `Child` is, of course, sensitive to changes of `Father`. Also, I don't know the Windows ABI so I can only point out the source for the differences, not a reason about the specific sizes used on Windows.

Comment: @Subhajit The total size of the base class is _not_ only 4 bytes.  It is 8 bytes in both cases.  The surprising part is that adding data members in the `Child` doesn't increase the total size.

Comment: And of course, this behavior has nothing to do with C compatibility, at least not directly.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're using a `#pragma`, which probably makes your
compiler non-standard; I don't know what impact it might have
here, but it certainly means that the compiler may do wierd
things (including laying out the class in a way that is totally
incompatible with any other interface).

Having said that, I get the same results with or without the
`#pragma`: with g++, these results mirror yours; with VC++,
I get 12 for the derived class in all cases.  The first thing to
note is that whether `private` or `public`, and whether g++ or
VC++, the size of the base class is always 8.  This is due to
alignment considerations: both compilers try to keep `int`
aligned on a multiple of four, and in order to do this in an
array of `Father`, the total size of `Father` must be 8, with
three bytes of padding after the `c`.  Since `Child` also
contains (indirectly through inheritance) an `int`, the same
alignment considerations apply.  At first glance we would expect
`Child` to have a size of 12: the 8 bytes of `Father`, plus
1 byte for its data, plus 3 bytes padding for alignment.  This
is the case with VC++.  However, the C++ standard allows
something called "empty base class optimization" (because it was
originally designed to allow empty base classes to not occupy
memory): what it says is that when used as a base class, the
derived class can reuse any padding in the base.  So `Child` can
put its member `e` at the address of `Father` + 5 (since that's
where the padding in `Father` begins), and thus, only needs
6 bytes (rounded up to 8 for alignment reasons).

Why VC++ doesn't do this optimization, I don't know; perhaps
they were influenced by the name of the optimization.  (They do
do it when the base class has no data members.)  Why g++ would
only do it if there are private members, and not public, is even
stranger, but the standard doesn't require it.

Note that when the optimization is applied, something like:

```
Father* p1 = new Child;
Father* p2 = new Child;
memcpy( p2, p1, sizeof(Father) );
```

may have surprizing consequences, size the space actually
occupied by `Father` may be smaller than what `sizeof`
indicates.  This may account for the logic behind the choice of
g++: `memcpy` is not valid if the class has private members, so
they can apply it; it would be valid if all of the members are
public (and a few other conditions), so they don't apply it, in
order to avoid breaking things like the above.  (Adding
a constructor, which also makes `memcpy` illegal, causes g++ to
apply the optimization.)